I am international anyway

When I was zero, I was Central African.
When I was one, I was Japanese.
When I was two, I was Laotian.
When I was three, I was Dominican.
When I was four, I was Danish.
When I was five, I was Barbadian.
When I was six, I was Estonian.
When I was seven, I was Beninese.
When I was eight, I was Georgian.

Can you tell what nationality I had when I was nine?
Hint:

 Keep in mind that this is a yes/no question.


Heck, I don't even know what nationality you had when you were three!

@msh210 Dominican Republic, to be exact.

It isn't possible to tell the nationality 'when you were nine', because...

 ...there is no common national flag that contains a section featuring four quadrants of black, yellow, red, and white.

What?? Well, take a look at the other 9 listed above...

 

 If we look at the national flags for these countries and then compare them with the International Maritime Signalling Flags for numbers we can see that the designs of each of the maritime flags can be seen (pretty much) somewhere within the designs of the national flag, with corresponding colours and shapes.

 The design for a number 9 flag, though, involves four colours that don't commonly appear in national flags together, and particularly not in this desired orientation.

Although, saying that...

 ...with a little rotation, you might be a member of the Bandera Maya people!




Was just about to post an answer saying that they were American (from the state of Maryland). +1

Although it's usually more of a burgundy than red, in that case.

Arghhh couldn’t find the flag well done!!!

So mad I didn’t just write a partial I had a Belgian commune in mind!! Arghh it was a yes or no question darn it

Once I realised what was going on, it was a proper light bulb moment. I've done something similar to this myself before with letters!

I saw it was nautical flag related after typing something like ‘international flags’ on google images getting seriously lucky and seeing the number 1 resembling a Japanese flag, I then spent an hour looking for a country flag for number 9 but couldn’t find one. Came back and saw I was sniped. Damn this site! Admittedly it was definitely just sheer luck as opposed to a stroke of genius so I wouldn’t have felt too good about this solve anyways.

A vexillologist reading this just added a new goal to their bucket list...
